# Proving a bounded sequence of positive numbers question

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Any hints on how to start.

I looked at the definitions, but I couldn't get anywhere. Maybe I need to use a theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the gaps: there exists a subsequence $\;\{a_{n_k}\}\;$ such that $\;\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k}=t\in\Bbb R\;$ . If $\;t\neq0\;$ then by arithmetic of limits we get

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(a_{n_k}+\frac1{a_{n_k}}\right)=t+\frac1t\neq\infty$$

Get your contradiction now.

Comment: I have not learnt about subsequences, is it possible to do it without them?

Comment: @George On the top of my head, I can't see how. But perhaps somebody later will post a way to do it. Haven't you then studied Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, right?

Comment: Thanks. Nope not yet